# Find a string in multiple files using grep

Tags: regex, windows, grep

I have a folder with sub-folders inside, all have many types of files. I want to search for a word inside the `.css`-files. I am using Windows 7 and I have `grep`.

How I can use `grep` to :

1. Find pattern and print it
2. Give file name (and path) if pattern found

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Actually you don't need `find`. Just use:

```
grep -R --include=*.css -H pattern .
```

this will recurse and look for all *.css in subdirectories, while -H will show the filename.

Comment: No problem, the dot is where to start recursing from and represents the current directory.

Comment: I have some questions: 1.can I use `or` for file type `(txt|css)` 2.How I can search for files names and types ?

Answer (score 0):

```
find folder/ -name "*.css" |xargs grep "your-pattern"
```

You will need to install cygwin to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if the files in which we have to look for, has pattern then we can use this.
Consider I'm looking for pattern "cardlayout" in files named `chap1.lst chap2.lst` and so on.
then the command

```
grep -e 'cardlayout' ` find . -name "chap??.lst"`
```

hope this would help